# How to automatically create and link a record in table B after insert in table A

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider this scenario: I have a table `Person` which has a link to table `Address` as a one-to-many relationship (omitting constraints here for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    AddressId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Address (
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Street NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    City NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
    ZipCode NVARCHAR(20) NULL
)
```

Now, if a record is inserted into the `Person` table, I would like to automatically create an empty record in the `Address` table (if the `AddressId` column is `NULL`) and link that new `Address` to the new `Person` record. So in other words, I want to create a record in the `Address` table and want to update `Person.AddressId` for every inserted `Person` without an `Address`.

Since I am accessing the database from different applications using different ORMs and different business classes, I do not want to add that functionality in the business classes (multiple times), but rather in a DB trigger on the `Person` table.

1. Is it good practice to do that in a DB trigger?
2. What is the best implementation for the trigger ("best" meaning a good tradeoff between performance and readability)?

I could implement the trigger using a `WHILE` loop iterating over all records in `inserted` and then adding a record for each of the inserted `Person`s - if they have no `Address` assigned yet. However, this does not feel like the right approach if lots of `Person` records are created in a bulk operation (like a big import for example). Is it possible to perform this in one SQL statement with better performance?

Comment: sounds like a weird design and scenario.

Comment: @FLICKER: Details would be helpful... The original scenario is not about persons and addresses, but it is more complex. I just tried to simplify the scenario to focus on the problematic part.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an after insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER personInsTrigger ON Person AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Address (Id, Street, City, ZipCode)
    SELECT AddressId, NULL, NULL, NULL
    FROM INSERTED
END
```

I would also recommend that you consider setting up proper foreign/primary key constraints between the two tables.  `Address.Id` would be a primary key, and `Person.AddressId` would be a foreign key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this way, the two records are not linked to each other. Only the `Address` record is created, but the `Person`'s `AddressId` field is not set, right?
BTW: "omitting constraints here for brevity", as stated in my original post.